# Send parameters using php file_get_content function

Tags: php

Dear all,
How i send parameters using php file_get_content function.

```
$id='123';
$name='blah';
$response=file_get_contents('http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name');  
echo $response;
```

I need to send the $id and name value to abc.php page.Here the value passing **does not working**.also i chk ?id="$id"&name="$name" value.It's also not working. But the straite parameter **works**.say-

```
$response=file_get_contents('http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=123&name=blah');
```

Now is their any Kind heart who can help me to send the 2 parameters $id and $name to abc.php?

Thanks
riad

Answer (score 7):

Single quotes inhibit variable substitution.

```
$response=file_get_contents("http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name");
```

Don't forget to URL-encode all parameters though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable variable substitution in a string, you have to use double quotes:

```
$response=file_get_contents("http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes. i.e `"http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$response = file_get_contents(sprintf("http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=%s&name=%s", $id, $name));
```

Answer (score -1):

A safer way is to use http_build_query which escapes the variables properly:

```
$response=file_get_contents('http://localhost/abc/abc.php?'.http_build_query(['id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name]));
```

Answer (score -2):

put this thing in double quotes:

```
$response=file_get_contents("http://localhost/abc/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name");
```

Thanks.